# OpenGL Coordinate Transformation Sceen to World

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, coordinate-transformation

I'm writing a MFC c++ application that uses OpenGL. The program allows for drawing and manipulating of objects in 3D. Right now I want to find the coordinates, in the same coordinate space that my objects are drawn in, anywhere I click my mouse on the screen.

So far I've been using a combination of glReadPixels and gluUnProject and it has been working but only when I click my mouse somewhere where an object has already been drawn. If I click anywhere outside my object the coordinates obtained are completely off.

So I was wondering how to change my code so that I can find the coordinates in the coordinate space my objects are in anywhere on the screen. Here's the code I've been using:

```
GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble ox, oy, oz;//the coordinates I need
GLfloat winZ = 0.0;
::glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
::glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,    projectionMatrix);
::glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelviewMatrix);
GLfloat winX = (float)point.x;//point.x and point.y are the mouse coordinates
GLfloat winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)point.y;

::glReadPixels( winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

gluUnProject((GLdouble)winX, (GLdouble)winY, (GLdouble)winZ, modelviewMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewport, &ox, &oy, &oz);
```

Comment: Your screen is 2D, your world is 3D. Every 2D position on the screen corresponds not to a 3D point, but to a ray/line/line segment. Just out of curiosity, what does `gluUnProject` return if `winZ` is 1?

Comment: It still returns a 1 every time even if winZ is 1. And could you please elaborate on how every 2D point corresponds to a ray/line/line segment? what would be the magnitude and direction?

Answer (score 0):

`gluUnProject` takes window space coordinates and un-projects them with the inverse of the world-view-projection-viewport transformations. It has no clue if the coordinates correspond to an existing object or not.

When you clear the depth buffer, it is initialized everywhere with a value that is read as 1.0 with `glReadPixels`.

When visible fragments of an object are drawn they will pass the depth test and will override the depth value with a smaller value for every pixel intersecting these fragments.

This means that every time you read a pixel in the depth buffer with a value of 1.0, this means that nothing visible has been drawn in that pixel and this is where the result you obtain is completely off.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right the winZ does always return a 1.0 when I read from a point without visible fragments. So in that case is it impossible to achieve what I'm trying to do with my current method? If so what other functions should I use?
I think what I need is a screen to world transformation?